# Doing a groupby only on common column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a query on how to do groupby  on the values which are common to the keys on which we are doing a groupby. Its very hard for me to describe the exact problem in words.

I have the table below in this format.

[image]

Now I want a dataframe which looks like the one below with groupby on code and Name which have common type and alias.

[image]

So if you can see [Card,Cardio] and name "cardio" is common to the top three entries . So thats how we get the first row in our resultant table. Since Heart is common to only type A and C, thats how we get the third row and so on.

I don't have any code on how to do this and cant think also of any solution on how to achieve this result.

And sorry for the phrasing of the question and I will be really grateful if you have any rephrasing suggestions

**Edit - Code for Type E will be 2 in first table**

Comment: It was not letting me add tables. So I just added the picture

Comment: 5th line first table, type E shouldn't be code 2?

Answer (score 1):

I consider this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Code': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
'Name': ['cardio', 'cardio', 'cardio', 'Lung', 'Lung'],
'Alias': [["Card","cardio","Heart"],
          ["Card","cardio","Bypass"],
          ["Card","cardio","Heart"],
          ["Brea","Bre"],
          ["Vrea","Bre"]
         ]
  })
```

Lest first use explode to get rid of this nasty list from "Alias" column:

```
df = df.explode('Alias').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then we group by columns that you have specified and collect "Type"s to a list:

```
df = df.groupby( ["Code","Name","Alias"])['Type'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

We have to change dtype of column "Type" to string to be able to group by this column (you can reverse it in the end):

```
df["Type"] = df["Type"].apply(str)
```

I the final step just group by again by all columns beside "Alias" and collect "Alias" valus to a list.

```
df = df.groupby(["Code","Name","Type"])['Alias'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

This results with deisred output:

```
Code    Name    Type            Alias
1       cardio  ['A', 'B', 'C'] [Card, cardio]
1       cardio  ['A', 'C']      [Heart]
1       cardio  ['B']           [Bypass]
2       Lung    ['D', 'E']      [Bre]
2       Lung    ['D']           [Brea]
2       Lung    ['E']           [Vrea]
```

I hope it will help you :)